# How to use common connection open and close for all event?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am working on asp.net project, in that i am doing select/delete/update/insert operations for that i am creating SqlConnection, SqlCommand instances in all those events. Is there any idea to use a common Class to create and use SqlConnection and other SQL Operations.

```
    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into tJob(colName) values (value));
```

Comment: Show your code you already have

Comment: If you are okay and you can, use EF that will handle most of ur problems

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580534/common-method-to-get-data-from-database-with-custom-return-type-data-access-lay/27580652#27580652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly , here's the basics.

```
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString);

Try
   conn2.Open()

   '....Write your code logic here
   SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into tJob(colName) values (value));

   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

Catch ex As Exception

Finally
   conn2.Close()
   conn2.Dispose()
End Try
```

**EDIT**
If you are looking for a common for the whole web project, it should be place in `web.config` file inside `<connectionStrings>` tag.

Please refer below sample.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DatabaseNameHere;Integrated Security=False;User ID = UserNameHere ; Password = PasswordHere " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

To call it in behind code: (*please see sample vb code below*), you can call it every page behind code.

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("DatabaseNameHere").ConnectionString)
```

Comment: This helps only for that web page only. I want to use the connection for whole project.

Comment: @Sam1604 if you are looking the connection for the whole project it should be in web.config

Comment: @Sam1604 see EDIT answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You may define SqlConnection as global variable for your page, not for method, and attach a connection string. The same way to SqlCommand, and every time just changing the code of SqlCommand and it's parameters.

```
private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your_connection_string");
private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

}

protected void MyMethod(){
    cmd.CommandText = "my_first_stored_procedure";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("myparam", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
    //...
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}

protected void MyMethod2(){
    cmd.CommandText = "my_second_stored_procedure";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("myparam", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
    //...
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

and so on...